# Force Colloquy not to use built-in Growl notifications

Tags: macos, notifications, irc, growl, colloquy

Whenever Colloquy needs to pop up a notification (for example, when you are PM'd), it uses its built-in Growl notifications, which really annoy me because they stay on the screen until they are clicked (at least `NOTICE`'s do anyways).

I'd like to make Colloquy use the Growl that I have installed on my Mac, not its built-in Growl notifications. That way, I could change its preferences from the Growl `.prefpane` and it would match the look of all my other notifications. I seem to remember this being possible (maybe in a bug report or something), but I can't remember how. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's because Colloquy is using it's own installed version of Growl, it's just because it's changing the settings used when it displays its notifications.

Comment: @Mark No, that's not true. If it were using the system-wide Growl, its preferences would be configurable in the `.prefpane`. It uses its own built-in Growl as a safeguard for computers that don't have Growl already installed.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry.

Comment: @Mark No need to apologize; we're all friends here on SU `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I lead myself to the solution from a [posting](http://groups.google.com/group/growldiscuss/browse_thread/thread/66e06c289df29de7) on Google Groups. Turns out you have to force Colloquy to run in 32-bit mode in order to get it to show up in the Growl `.prefpane`:

[image: Colloquy 32-bit]

Then, you can customize the Colloquy notifications however you choose:

[image: Grown screenshot]

Comment: Tried this fix with Colloquy 2.3, 2.4 and nightly builds r4630 and r5138 with OSX Lion & Growl 1.3 (Appstore), but it didn't work.

Comment: works for me on lion with growl 1.2.2 and colloquy 2.3 (4617), thx

Comment: @Chris Burgess the growl api changed in 1.3 (something to do with getting on the app store) so many apps aren't compatible with it. I've reverted to 1.2.2 on lion and so far so good.

Comment: @cerberos Thanks. There are good alternatives now too; I ended up switching to Textual from the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

Colloquy has a preference under Alerts: “...and keep on screen until activated.”.  Are you sure you don’t have that turned on?

I’ll set aside their stupid (and abusive, and terrible) behavior of bundling in Growl instead of using the System’s growl and/or prompting to install Growl (ala Adium).

Comment: Yes, I've turned that off in the preferences. It's not the staying on the screen I have an issue with, it's the "getting colloquy to use built-in growl" problem. Thanks anyways.